# Apache POI recording only 1 row in the spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am using selenium and java to scrape data on a specific site, but with the code below I can write only 1 data in the spreadsheet, it is not recording all the data in sequence as it should be.

I can't structure the loop correctly.

```
public void gravarDados() throws IOException {

    int i = 0;
    File localPlanilha = new File("tools/resultado_da_pesquisa.xlsx");

    FileInputStream planilhaExistente = new FileInputStream(localPlanilha);

    XSSFWorkbook plan = new XSSFWorkbook(planilhaExistente);

    XSSFSheet sheetExistente = plan.getSheetAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i < inicio; i++) {
    // Writing data
    sheetExistente.getRow(2).createCell(5).setCellValue(TitulosHoteis.get(i).getText());


    FileOutputStream fechandoArquivo = new FileOutputStream(localPlanilha);

    plan.write(fechandoArquivo);
  }
}
```

[image: poi]

Answer (score 4):

Currently you are getting only the 0th element.

You need to iterate the below with a for loop

`TitulosHoteis.get(i).getText())`;

to write the result to rows and columns.

Please modify it as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < inicio; i++) {
    // Writing data
    sheetExistente.getRow(i+2).createCell(5).setCellValue(TitulosHoteis.get(i).getText());

}
    FileOutputStream fechandoArquivo = new FileOutputStream(localPlanilha);

    plan.write(fechandoArquivo);
```

Comment: I changed the code, put a for and iterated, but still recording only the first line.

Comment: You need to iterate row or column also. Updated the answer

Comment: Change the code, I tried some options here, but it didn't work.

Do you want access to the complete code so you can run it on your machine and see the behavior?

Comment: I would love to help if you still have not resolved this issue

Comment: I haven't solved the problem yet, it is recording only the results of the first page, it does not record the rest of the research.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, could you grant me full so access so I could run it my local and figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before you're not iterating over the rows as the row number stays the same in your code, however there is also another problem with your code. You need to check if a row exists and if it doesn't create it before you can set a cell value of that row.

It should look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inicio; i++) {
  Row row = sheetExistente.getRow(2+i);
  if (row == null) sheetExistente.createRow(2+i);
  sheetExistente.getRow(2 + i).createCell(5).setCellValue(TitulosHoteis.get(i).getText());
}
```

Comment: Hi, the code worked, but it only writes data from the first page that is scraped, when the robot moves to the second page, it no longer writes to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Are you sure you're writing each scraped page in a new seperate file and you're not failing to overwrite the previous one? If you don't want to write each page to a new file you need to store the last index of the last row and write from there. 'int i = 0' should be int 'i = lastRow'. Don't forget to save the lastRow after you've iterated over the rows.