# Apache Poi: Exception when reading spreadsheet data

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm reading data from a spreadsheet and an exception is occurring, but I can't figure out where it is.

```
 int quantidade_linhas = sheet.getLastRowNum();

        for (int i = 0; i < quantidade_linhas; i++) {

            String nomes = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            String sobrenomes = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

            System.out.println("Dados: " + nomes + " " + sobrenomes);

        }
        PlanilhaSerLida.close();
        System.out.println("Fechando a planilha!\n");

    }
```

**Error Console:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   arquivo.lerDados.main(lerDados.java:32)

Line 32 where the error is pointed out is precisely the string `nomes`

[image: erro]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An excel spreadsheet can have blank rows that are empty and thus have no cell values. I'd first debug your program with this code, put it right under the for-loop declaration:

```
System.out.println("Row " + i + " null?: " + (sheet.getRow(i) == null))
```

That prints for each row the index and whether the row is null or not. After that you can decide to either fix the spreadsheet, make your program ignore empty (null) rows or do both.

Also a tip, if one of the rows contains a numerical value it will cause an exception since it won't auto convert the int to a string. Make a utility function that checks cell.getCellType() for a (CellType) string or a numerical value and then converts when needed.

Comment: Can you check this question too, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420348/apache-poi-recording-only-1-row-in-the-spreadsheet/60420442?noredirect=1#comment106886250_60420442